# AngularJS input states not working in asp

Tags: html, asp.net, angularjs

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Login.aspx.cs" Inherits="Staffing_Tool.Login" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head runat="server">
    <script src="scripts/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="Styles/Login.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <title>Login</title>
</head>
<body data-ng-app="">
    <form runat="server" name="myForm" novalidate>
        <div class="circle logo">
            <span></span><p>Welcome<br/>to<br/>MCBC Staffing Tool</p>
        </div>
        <div class="loginForm">
            <h4> Login Information</h4>
            <input type="text" class="text" name="userName" placeholder="Enter Username" data-ng-model="userName" required/>
            <span data-ng-show="myForm.userName.$touched && myForm.userName.$invalid">Username is required.</span>
            <input type="password" name="password" class="text" placeholder="Enter Password" data-ng-model="password" required/>
            <span data-ng-show="myForm.password.$touched && myForm.password.$invalid">Password is required.</span>
            <a href="#">Forgot your password?</a>
            <asp:Button ID="btnLogin" runat="server" CssClass="btn blue animate" Text="Log in"></asp:Button>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I am new to angularJS, and above is a simple login form I have created in asp.
Everything is working fine but error span for input fields are not working.

First I thought, angularJS itself is not working so I added a h1 tag as follows after my userName field to test that:

```
<h1>{{userName}}</h1>
```

And its showing the value typed in the field.

Then I tried following:

```
<h1>{{myForm.userName.$valid}}</h1>
```

But it's not showing anything.

Then I tried placing the html part of my code (leaving the first line), in a simple .html file and ran it, and everything worked smoothly.

Please let me know why its not working in .aspx file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because you are working with Asp.net Web Forms.

name attirbute is removed from Asp.net 4.0
Add following thing in System.Web Section in Web.Config

```
<pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" />
```

NOte: Also set id attribute - Whatever you set id that will be set to name as well. 
Example

in above case name will be X

Hope it works for you :)

Comment: Thanks for your response, I already have System.Web section in my web.config file. Do you want me to add anything particular in that section. Also I tried with id attribute, but its still not working.

Comment: It worked after I removed runat="server" from my form tag. Thank you so much for your help.